# get count of numbers in an infinite sequence when it reaches condition

Tags: f#

i want to use the functional way to count this and i want to count them efficiently so i do not want to store the sequence, just go through it and count the numbers

```
let conjv2 x =
    let next n = match n%2 with
                 |0 -> n/2
                 |_ -> n*3+1
    Seq.initInfinite next
    |> Seq.takeWhile(fun n -> n > 1)
    |> Seq.length
```

this does not work and returns 0 for any positive number, it is the 3n+1 conjecture and i am finding it really hard to count them efficiently, this code works fine but i want to do it the functional way :

```
let conj x =
    let mutable ansa = x
    let mutable cycles = 1
    while ansa > 1 do
        cycles <- cycles+1
        ansa <- match ansa%2 with
                |0 -> ansa/2
                |_ -> ansa*3+1
    cycles
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem with the sample is that you're using `Seq.initInfinite` instead of `Seq.unfold`.

- `Seq.initInfinite` calls the specified function with the index of the element as argument (0, 1, 2, ..)
- `Seq.unfold` calls the specified function with the state generated by the previous iteration

Note that your code also does not use the argument `x` and so your function ends up being `'a -> int` rather than `int -> int` which is what you'd expect - this is a good indication that there is something wrong!

To fix this, try something like this:

```
let conjv2 x =
    let next n = match n%2 with
                 |0 -> n/2
                 |_ -> n*3+1
    Seq.unfold (fun st -> let n = next st in Some(n, n)) x
    |> Seq.takeWhile(fun n -> n > 1)
    |> Seq.map (fun v -> printfn "%A" v; v)
    |> Seq.length
```

The function passed to `unfold` needs to return an option with the new state & a value to emit. To generate infinite sequence, we always return `Some` and the emitted values are the intermediate states.

This returns values that are smaller by 2 than your original `conj`, because `conj` starts with 1 (rather than 0) and it also counts the last value (while here, we stop before `ansa=1`). So you'll need to add 2 to the result.

Comment: Seq.unfold (fun st -> Some(st, next st)) x

Comment: this works fine but adds the first element which is what i need but other than that thank you. but for the problem of efficiency this is still much slower than conj is there a way to make the sequence count while going through the elements instead of saving them and then doing .length?

Comment: It's slower if you keep the '|> Seq.map (fun v -> printfn "%A" v; v)
' in the function. I bet Tomas added it to see the sequence unfolding, but it's not needed.